# Parent listen to child emit event in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way for the parent component listen to its child component emmited custom event?

```
// -- child comp
const addnewbtn  = {
    template : '<div><button v-on:click="showform">Add New Task</button><form v-show="form" v-on:submit.prevent="addnewtask"><input type="text" v-model="taskname" /><button>Add</button></form></div>',
  data(){
    return {
        taskname : '',
      form : false
    }
  },
  methods : {
    showform(){
        if( this.form ){
        this.form = false;
      }else{
        this.form = true;
      }
    },
    addnewtask(){
      this.$emit('add-task',this.taskname);
    }
  },
}

// -- parent comp
Vue.component('todolist',{
    components : { addnewbtn },
    data(){
    return {
        todoitems : [
        { name : 'Task 1', checked : false },
        { name : 'Task 2', checked : false },
        { name : 'Task 3', checked : false },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods : {
    makeitdone(item){
        if( this.todoitems[item].checked ){
        this.todoitems[item].checked = false;
      }else{
        this.todoitems[item].checked = true;
      }
    },
    removeitem(item){
        this.todoitems.splice(item,1);
    },
    addtask(){
        alert();
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.$root.$on('add-task',function(){
        alert();
    });
  }
});
```

tried

```
this.$root.$on('add-task',function(){
  alert();
});
```

or

```
this.$parent.$on('add-task',function(){
  alert();
});
```

but unfortunately, neither from two works. How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your parent component, simply adding listen `@add-task`

```
<addnewbtn @add-task="addtask" />
```

then it can listen for the event which is emitted from children

```
  this.$emit('add-task',this.taskname);
```

Comment: is there way to make the listen-to-child-emitted-event on the created instance of the parent component?

Comment: You don't need add listener to created hook, `@add-task` is enough.
Or you can use EventBus https://medium.com/easyread/vue-as-event-bus-life-is-happier-7a04fe5231e1

Comment: i see, thank you, will accept your answer in a moment